# How can validate NSDATE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

**How to find one text field value is within past 60 day excluding current date.**

For example if I enter value in text field is **20-July-2012** using `Date Picker`.Then I click **submit**,it'll check that specific is date is within 60 days or not. If the values are entered which is before 60 days an alert message is displayed. The values are retrieved from api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSTimeInterval dateTime;
if ([pickerDate isEqualToDate:today])   //pickerDate is a NSDate
{
     NSLog (@"Dates are equal");
}
dateTime = ([pickerDate timeIntervalSinceDate:today] / 86400);  
if(dateTime < 0) //Check if visit date is a past date, dateTime returns - val
{
     NSLog (@"Past Date");
}
else 
{   
     NSLog (@"Future Date");
}
```

Change the value of 86400 to suit your query.In this case, it is the number of seconds we want to compare.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the text into an `NSDate`. Then use

`timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]`

There are a couple of ways to convert text into an `NSDate`. You can format the text correctly and then use `dateWithString` or you can convert everything into numbers, multiply them out, and one of the `dateWithTimeInterval` methods.

If you want the user to be able to enter "July" (plain text month) then you might want to write a method that converts months into their numerical equivalents with string matching.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *lastDate; //your date I hope you have created it
NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval lastDiff = [lastDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSTimeInterval todaysDiff = [todaysDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSTimeInterval dateDiff = lastDiff - todaysDiff; // number of seconds
int days = dateDiff/(60*60*24); // 5.8 would become 5 as I'm taking int
```

Answer (score 0):

**How do you define 60 days?**

You may want to use `NSCalendar` `-dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:` **to ensure your 60 days really are 60 days**.

`NSCalendar` also provides `-components:fromDate:` and `-dateFromComponents:` which are very nice when dealing with date components.

**If 60 days do not need to be true calendar days** (daylight saving time switches, astronomical time corrections, stuff like that), you can just have fun with `NSDate` and the time interval methods alone.